# Why is my python/pandas code not filtering the Termination date correctly?

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

My python script imports an xlsx file, strips out some IDs, and then is supposed to filter out Termination Dates based on my "term_date" variable. Since today is June 12th, I would not expect any Termination dates past March 14th 2018 to be in my output. However, I am seeing February Termination Dates. Any idea why?

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

TODAY = datetime.today().strftime("%d%m%Y")
term_date = (datetime.today() - timedelta(days=90))
#term_date = (pd.to_datetime('today') - pd.Timedelta(days=90))
remove_id = ['381998','201439']

df = pd.read_excel('Details.xlsx')
df = df[~df['Employee ID'].isin(remove_id)]
df['Termination Date'] = df['Termination Date'].astype(str)

df['Termination Date'] = df['Termination Date'].str.replace('nan', '1/1/2050')
df['Termination Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Termination Date'])
df['Hire Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Hire Date'])
df['Home Address Line 1'] = df['Home Address Line 1'].str.replace(',', '')
df['Home Address Line 2'] = df['Home Address Line 2'].str.replace(',', '')
df['Shipping Address Line 1'] = df['Shipping Address Line 1'].str.replace(',', '')
df['Shipping Address Line 2'] = df['Shipping Address Line 2'].str.replace(',', '')
df2 = df[df['Termination Date'] >= term_date]

df2.to_excel('roster_file2_' + TODAY + '.xlsx')
```

Example of my dataframe:

```
Employee ID Termination Date    Hire Date   Home Address Line 1
234254              2/1/2018    1/1/2015    20 Main St
675867              5/2/2018    1/1/2015    10 Elm St
345665              1/1/2050    1/1/2015    1 Chestnut St
974445              1/1/2050    1/1/2015    12 Cherry St
235465             11/3/2017    1/1/2015    9 Lucky St
```

Comment: Can you give us an excerpt of your dataframe (something like `df.to_dict().head()`) so we can replicate your issue? Otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: Yes, of course! I have added an excerpt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it look like an issue with datetime format. 
try pass `dayfirst=True` when converting to date time

```
df.TerminationDate = pd.to_datetime(df.TerminationDate,dayfirst=True)

df[df.TerminationDate >= term_date]
Out[519]: 
EmployeeID TerminationDate    HireDate   HomeAddress
2      345665      2050-01-01  01/01/2015  1 ChestnutSt
3      974445      2050-01-01  01/01/2015   12 CherrySt
```

Comment: Oh I see why adding dayfirst=true works. According to the documentation:

Specify a date parse order if arg is str or its list-likes. If True, parses dates with the day first, eg 10/11/12 is parsed as 2012-11-10. Warning: dayfirst=True is not strict, but will prefer to parse with day first (this is a known bug, based on dateutil behavior).

I guess it is the difference between pandas interpreting **"month then day"** vs **"day then month"**